# How do I use SQL to extract custom field data for JIRA issues?

Tags: mysql, jira

I am trying to pull data from the `jiaissue` table, along with data from custom fields for the same issue. Some of the custom fields have their values in the `customfieldvalue` table and some others in `customfieldoption` table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT i.id, i.pkey
FROM jiraissue i
JOIN project p on i.project = p.id and p.id = 111 and i.resolutiondate IS NOT NULL
JOIN issuetype it on it.id = i.issuetype and it.id = 01
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cfv.issue, cf.cfname, cfo.customvalue 
             from customfieldvalue cfv
             join customfield cf on cf.ID = cfv.CUSTOMFIELD and cf.id = 303
             join customfieldoption cfo on cfo.id = cfv.stringvalue and cfo.parentoptionid is null and cfo.customvalue = 'X') u on u.ISSUE = i.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cfv.issue, cf.cfname, cfv.textvalue 
              FROM customfieldvalue cfv
              JOIN customfield cf ON cf.ID = cfv.CUSTOMFIELD AND cf.id = 505) fci ON fci.ISSUE = i.ID
```

The above code works, but it's slow. The underlying database is MySQL.

Comment: I am unclear about what your question is.

Comment: Not sure how else to explain it, unfortunately. Jiraissue table stores all incidents. I need to select once that are belong to specific project and have specific issuetype and then also show custom values for custom fields associated with it. Hope it helps.

Comment: You presented some code, but what is your actual question? Does the code work or is it broken? If it's broken, how is it broken and not doing what you want? If it works, does it do everything that you need? If it works but doesn't do everything, what else do you need?

Comment: Sorry, it works, but as I mentioned it's too slow. I wonder if I am doing it right. Is there a different way to do it? How would you do it?

Comment: One more thing. I am saying that it's too slow because if I'd run the same in UI as a filter it runs in 4 sec. Via direct sql it takes ~2min. It tell me that it's possible to run it faster, but I am not sure if I am missing a join perhaps?

Comment: What database are you using? (Also, note that the UI filters results come from the Lucene index, not the database, so it's not directly comparable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has traditionally had very poor performance when using subqueries, since it did not use indexes or fare very well at the query optimization part. (I believe that this has been improved somewhere around MySQL 5.6.x.)

In the meantime, one thing you can do is to materialize the queries yourself using temp tables. I removed the `project` and `issuetype` tables from the query because they were not needed simply to filter on the relevant attributes in the issue. Lastly, I also optimized away the extra joins to the `customfield` table. (Since you're already querying it by the specific custom field ID, you presumably already know the field name.)

```
create temporary table cfu AS
select cfv.issue, cfo.customvalue 
from customfieldvalue cfv
join customfieldoption cfo on cfo.id = cfv.stringvalue and cfo.parentoptionid is null
WHERE  cfo.customvalue = 'X' AND CFV.customfield=303;

create temporary table cffci AS
SELECT cfv.issue, cfv.textvalue 
FROM customfieldvalue cfv
WHERE CFV.customfield=505;

alter table cfu add index idx_cfu_issue(issue);
alter table cffci add index idx_cffci_issue(issue);

select i.id, i.pkey, cfu.customvalue, cffci.textvalue
from jiraissue i
LEFT JOIN cfu on cfu.ISSUE = i.ID
LEFT JOIN cffci ON cffci.ISSUE = i.ID
WHERE i.resolutiondate IS NOT NULL AND i.project=111 AND i.issuetype=01
```

Comment: Scott, sorry for delay and thank you, it worked for me.